# Storing passwords securely for authentication in java

Tags: java, passwords

I have just started to learn security programming in java. Encryption, decryption, salts, etc.

I created a simple program to decrypt and encrpt a password but the problem is when it comes to saving the password.

Saving an encrypted password to a file is simple but storing the file out of access of a user or hacker is the problem.

I checked [this site](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-donts-dos-and.html) but this doesn't explain about storing.

So where does that password get saved?

My code is not special: it just uses buffers reader and writer to retrieve a saved encrypted password from a file.

I'm using Windows on a standard PC.

Comment: But it somewhere in `AppData` is where i recomend. I think that is what you are asking

Comment: Yeah 3kings I understand. I had saved that file in appdata/romaing/mysecurtiy(as for trial) but it is accessible by anyone

Comment: Don't encrypt the password. SALT and hash the password.

Comment: OK Elliott, I will salt and hash it but where will I store that hashed password so that no one can access it.

Comment: @karatos5566 so you just simply save them to a file but encrypted. `The file contents that is`.  Hash the passwords with a SALT then write them to a file using an encryption algorithm to make it unreadable to the user.

Comment: Ok 3kings it is not that simple. Just think u will have a default password or create a password option for first time use of application. If I save the password to file and the file is deleted by someone then application will again reset.

Comment: You're confusing two problems here. 1. prevent a hacker from deleting your password database. This doesn't have much to do with Java and cryptography: your machine should be behind a firewall, and the database shouldn't be publicly accessible. 2. If an intruder, or a malicious employee, is able to read the password database, how to make sure all the passwords are not compromised. This is where salting and hashing (with a very strong, multi-pass hashing algorithm like bcrypt or PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 come into play: it must be impossible, even for you, to know a password even with access to the DB

Comment: Hi jb nizet,can u please help me to understand first point in your comment

Comment: Preventing access to a file has to do with file permissions. Have a look at the methods on `java.io.File`, in particular `setReadable()`. (PS. We don't all use Windows. )